# How to access current user in Django class based view

Tags: python, django

I cannot access current logged in user in Django class based view:

models.py:

```
class Userproject(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'pp'
        verbose_name_plural = u'pps'

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    related_name="project", verbose_name=_("Владелец проекта"))
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    name = models.TextField(u'Название проекта', unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата создания', 
        default=datetime.now(), db_index=True)
    date_until = models.DateTimeField(u'Оплачен по', default=datetime.now(), db_index=True)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
class UserprojectList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'userproject_list'
    queryset = Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    template_name = 'userproject_list.html'
```

when i navigate to url i see error:
**name 'self' is not defined**

if i change self.request.user  to request.user
the error is: **name 'request' is not defined**

Note that without user filtering view is working and shows data
django 1.8.5

Comment: do you mind to show your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just overwrite `get_queryset`:

```
@login_required
class UserprojectList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'userproject_list'
    template_name = 'userproject_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Also **you can't use decorators on classes**, so you have to write something like this:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class UserprojectList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'userproject_list'
    template_name = 'userproject_list.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserprojectList, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: This may not have been available at the time, but instead of the `@method_decorator(login_required)` decorator you can inherit the `django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin` mixin to your class which is neater.

Answer (score 6):

@pythad's answer is correct.  But on Django 1.9+, instead of the `dispatch` method,  you can use [django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to replace the old-style @login_required decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UserprojectList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'userproject_list'
    template_name = 'userproject_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do that in the `__init__` method:

```
@login_required
class UserprojectList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'userproject_list'
    template_name = 'userproject_list.html'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserprojectList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Userproject.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the class-based views you would need to override the get_queryset() method in order to have access to the self.request object attached to the instance of the view rather than do this at the class level. The Classy Class-Based Views site has more information: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.list/ListView/